# How to pass list of objects to a function

Tags: java, spring, function, object

I want to pass a List of objects to one of my functions.

Here's the code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/pages/generateReports")
public ModelAndView toGenerateReports(@ModelAttribute("forReports") @Valid Reports report){    

    List<Patients> patients = patientsDAO.listAllPatients(report.getDateFrom(), report.getDateTo());

    //tried printing what's in patients and surely it contains something

    GenerateReports reports = new GenerateReports();
    reports.generateReports(patients);

    return ...;
}

public class GenerateReports {
    public void generateReports(List<? extends Patients> patients) {

    ....some checkings here and all I get is an empty list... 

    }
}
```

What do I have to do to make it work?

Comment: debug and figure out? If you call a method with a non empty list as argument, the method gets a non empty list..

Comment: Oh sorry, a pretty stupid mistake I made, I wasn't able to modify the report.getDateTo() so I really do have a non-empty list. Thank you for pointing it out. :)

Comment: glad you figured it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks good to me, it should work. You can change `List<? extends Patients> patients` to `List<Patients> patients` but that should not change anything.